# How can I optimize code for extension function of Context, Fragment and Activity in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

The Code A is extension function for `Context`, `Fragment` and `Activity`.

I think it's redundant, how can I optimize it?

**Code A**

```
    fun Context.toast(msg: String){
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    
    fun Context.toast(@StringRes resId: Int){
        toast(getString(resId))
    }
    
    fun Context.toast(@StringRes resId: Int,msg: String){
        toast(getString(resId) + msg)
    }
    
    fun Context.toast(msg: String,@StringRes resId: Int){
        toast(msg + getString(resId))
    }
    
    //------------------------------------------------

    fun Fragment.toast(msg:String) {
        requireContext().toast(msg)
    }
    
    fun Fragment.toast(@StringRes resId: Int) {
        toast(requireContext().getString(resId))
    }
    
    fun Fragment.toast(@StringRes resId: Int, msg: String) {
        toast(requireContext().getString(resId) + msg)
    }
    
    fun Fragment.toast( msg: String, @StringRes resId: Int) {
        toast(msg+ requireContext().getString(resId))
    }
    
    //------------------------------------------------

    fun Activity.toast(msg: String){
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    
    fun Activity.toast(@StringRes resId: Int){
        toast(getString(resId))
    }
    
    fun Activity.toast(@StringRes resId: Int,msg: String){
        toast(getString(resId) + msg)
    }
    
    fun Activity.toast(msg: String,@StringRes resId: Int){
        toast(msg + getString(resId))
    }
```

Comment: you don't need to implement extension functions for `Activity`, since `Activity` extends `Context`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Context extension functions should be enough. You will be able to use it virtually in any place where a UI component is available.

We can remove extensions for `Activity` because `Activity` is an indirect subclass of `Context` class.

And we also can remove `Fragment` extensions because they are not useful until a fragment is attached to an activity (which is the context).

```
fun Context.toast(msg: String){
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

fun Context.toast(@StringRes resId: Int){
    toast(getString(resId))
}

fun Context.toast(@StringRes resId: Int,msg: String){
    toast(getString(resId) + msg)
}

fun Context.toast(msg: String,@StringRes resId: Int){
    toast(msg + getString(resId))
}
```

These functions can be used in an activity:

[image: Use of extension functions in Activity]

And in a fragment. It is logically correct and intentional that we must first get a reference to a `Context`:

[image: Use of extension functions in Fragment]

Comment: requireContext() can throw illegalStateException if Fragment is not attached!

Comment: @ArpitJ. Correct. That is stated in the documentation of this method: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requireContext().